# How is it possible to have a function that is both bounded an entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

For a  bounded function there must be an imaginary circle that contains it in the complex plane . However for a constant function the radius for this circle would be infinite making it unbounded!

Comment: Constant function?

Comment: You're confusing the boundedness of the domain with the boundedness of the range.

Comment: @GregoryGrant thanks :) big mistake on my part .

Comment: Once you've cleared up that point, read the following: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant function is the answer in two words. To clarify your doubt, why do you think it is impossible to find a function differentiable at all points on complex plain? (Constant function is the simplest example!)

---

Edit: From comments: I think I understand what you are confused about: By definition, a function (say $f:\mathbb{C}\to B\subset\mathbb{C}$) is entire if $f$ is differentiable at all points in plain $\mathbb{C}$, and it is said to be bounded if there is a "imaginary circle" containing $Range(f)\subset B$.

Comment: my doubt  pertains to the fact that i am visualizing the complex mapping as a an  infinite line . Is that wrong ?

Comment: Yes  it is wrong: Complex map deals with two planes!

Comment: Here's an example: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews//c2003/mobiustranformation/MobiusTranformationFigures/mat1005.gif

Comment: I mean the constant function as an infinite line . However i think i got the point . Thanks :)

Comment: I think I understand what you are confused about: By definition, an entire function (say $f:\mathbb{C}\to B$) is entire if $f$ is differentiable at all points in plain $\mathbb{C}$, and it is said to be bounded if there is a "imaginary circle" containing $Range(f)\subset B$.

Comment: Yes !  This was the confusion . I was making a big mistake !

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean constant functions can only be bounded by infinite circles? A constant function will be $f(z) = M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{C}$. That $M$ must have a finite modulus, and so $|f(z)| \leq |M| \, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: i was visualizing the constant function as an infinite line .

Comment: @v_g The image of a bounded function is contained in a disk. The graph of it isn't (the graph of it isn't even in $\mathbb{C}$ itself, it is in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and of course it is not bounded, because the domain isn't bounded).

Answer (score 0):

Constant functions (and by Liouville no other functions) are entire and bounded, the latter because there exists $R$ such that $|f(z)|<R$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.